# Java, How to find specific value from two dimensional array of doubles?

Tags: java, methods, multidimensional-array

I need to calculate the price between two locations, I have the following data structure which holds the price between areas:

```
                  Washington  Niagra Falls  New York
Washington        0,          6.30,         8.30
Niagra Falls      5.30,       0   ,         5.30
New York          3.20,       4.30,         0
```

How do I create a method that it will find the value in the two dimensional array based on the String X and String Y Locations?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
String Location X = "Washington";
String Location Y = "New York";

String XY = {"Washington", "Niagara Falls", "New York"}; 
//Cost of the trips
double[][] prices = { 
    {0,    6.30, 8.30},
    {5.30, 0,    5.30},
    {3.20, 4.30, 0   },
};
```

In the above case Washington -> New York should be `8.30`.

**Method should be something like this:**

```
public double calculateFees(String X, String Y){
    //add code here.

    double fares;
 return fares;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to figure out which array indices would apply.

```
public double calculateFees(String X, String Y){
    int xArrIdx=0;
    for(xArrIdx=0; xArrIdx<XY.length; xArrIdx++){
        if(XY[xArrIdx].equals(X)) break;

    }
    for(yArrIdx=0; yArrIdx<XY.length; yArrIdx++){
        if(XY[yArrIdx].equals(Y)) break;

    }

    return prices[xArrIdx][yArrIdx];
}
```

Making this handle cases where `X` or `Y` aren't in the array is left as an exercise to the reader.

Also make sure `prices` and `XY` are accessible from `calculateFees`. `XY` should also be a `String[]`, not a `String`.

Comment: Thanks, but one question how do you create method so fast? I mean are there any tips/techniques to create these methods?

Comment: @Jack Not really, besides remembering all the building blocks and how they fit together. Knowing concepts is key.

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the `X` from `XY`, say `i`.

Get the index of `Y` from `XY`, say `j`.

Get the fare using, `prices[i][j]`.

You might need to loop over the array XY testing for the given string each twice. You can save time by using a HashMap from String to Integer index instead.

Comment: "a HashMap from String to int index instead." Won't work, need to use `Integer` objects instead.